# Convert these to guitar tabs?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, tablature

These are the chord symbols. I don't know much about these chords but am quite experienced with guitar tabs.

b5 b5 b5 d6 F#6 F#6 d6 d6 d6 b5 d6 c#6 c#6 c#6 A5 b5

Comment: The context will help - what song is it ? Is each symbol one bar, one beat ? Are they written as capitals and lower case ?

Comment: As a convention, I see capital letters meaning major and lower-case meaning minor.

Comment: So do I. However, Johnny is a newbie.And one of each may suffice.

Comment: And - if it's a '5' chord it's neither maj. or min...

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understood it correctly, here you go:

[image]

There are hundreds of other voicings but these are the ones I most frequently use.

Answer (score 1):

You may see new chords in the future so I'd highly recommend to use `Guitar Pro` software : click `Note` on toolbar then click `Chord...` then you can select your chord.
 this website is also good if you don't have access to this software : [all-guitar-chords.com](http://www.all-guitar-chords.com/).
You will find all chords existed up to now !
Additionally,I found it very **beneficial**, interesting and easy to know chord patterns . all of us `need` to know them...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to begin by saying that an X5 chord is any chord that is made up of a root and the fifth. So a B5 chord will be made up of a B and an F#. A C5 chord will be made up of C and G.

And a 6 chord can be a chord that has the root, fifth and sixth added.

I am leaving the third (major and minor) ambiguous as I am assuming you are playing some sort of distorted guitar and you are looking for power voicings....

That being said, this is a possible interpretation of the chord in tab:

[image: HERE IS THE TAB]